# String comparison in groovy script not working

Tags: groovy, string-comparison

I am trying to compare 2 Strings in groovy script. both have same value but they are in different case while m trying compare it using equalsIgnoreCase still it is showing not equals.

Here is my code:

```
def st1=Austin
def ct=AUSTIN
  if(st1.equalsIgnoreCase(ct)){
                        log.info  "city equals"
                    }
                    else{
                        log.info "not eq"
                    }
```

it's printing "not eq".I tried toString() and toUpperCase methods.Plz help me out

Comment: What's your real code?  That's not valid Groovy.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake.code script that is too long.here  is def st1="Austin" and def ct="AUSTIN".please consider this

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the erroneous post. I got my problem I was working with db. it gives me value with some extra spaces. So my comparison was not working. later I used

> trim() 
>   to remove it.